# Probability Table

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

For the following joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, find the marginal probability $Pr(Y=2)$ , if $X$ and $Y$ are mutually independent. In the table below, blanks represent unknown probabilities that have to be determined should the value be required in the calculations.
[image]

I suspect I might have to solve some complicated linear system of equations, but I hope to find easier solutions.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Do the blanks mean the probability is $0$?  If so, $X,Y$ are clearly not independent as $X=1$ implies that $Y\neq 0$ yet, without knowledge of $X$, there is a positive probability that $Y=0$.  Also, the table seems incomplete...from the available data $\sum_n P(Y=n)<1$.

Comment: the blanks are unknown probabilities that have to be figured out should we require the value

Comment: That is entirely unclear from what you wrote.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: To your question;  I expect it really is just a matter of writing out the system of equations.  Not sure they are all linear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

We know the value of $P(X=1, Y=3)$ and $P(X=2, Y=3)$.

From there, you should be able to deduce the value of $P(X=2,Y=2)$ since we know $P(X=1, Y=2)$.

Comment: I saw it ... Thanks a lot for the insight!